# Show sum/total at the end of the table from two or more temporary tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, union, rollup

I have obtained two temporary tables which looks like follows:

Tmp1:

```
 groups______active_members
   a              2
   b              3
   c              7
```

Tmp2:

```
 groups_______participants
   a              1
   b              2
   c              4
```

I joined them with the code which looks like this:

```
SELECT
  tmp1.group AS groups,
  tmp1.active AS active_members,
  tmp2.participiants 
    FROM(
      (SELECT  name AS 'group',
       COUNT(`id`) AS 'active'
       FROM table1
      ) tmp1
      INNER JOIN
      (SELECT  name AS 'group',
       COUNT(`id`) AS 'participiants'   
       FROM table2
      ) tmp2 
ON tmp1.group=tmp2.group)
```

and obtained result like this:

```
 groups___active_members___participants
   a             2             1
   b             3             2
   c             7             4
```

I now want result as such:

```
 groups___active_members___participants
   a             2             1
   b             3             2
   c             7             4
 Total          12             7
```

Please help !! I also tried using UNION and WITH ROLLUP but as I'm new, I became clueless.Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**SQL**

```
SELECT tbl1.groups, tbl1.active_members, tbl2.participants
FROM tbl1
LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.groups = tbl2.groups
UNION ALL
SELECT "Total", SUM(active_members), SUM(participants) 
FROM (SELECT tbl1.groups, tbl1.active_members, tbl2.participants
      FROM tbl1
      LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.groups = tbl2.groups) AS tmptbl;
```

**Shema:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl1` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `groups` char(11) NOT NULL,
  `active_members` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl2` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `groups` char(11) NOT NULL,
  `participants` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT groups,active_members,participiants FROM (
SELECT 0 AS ord, tmp1.group AS groups,
  tmp1.active AS active_members,
  tmp2.participiants 
    FROM(
      (SELECT  name AS 'group',
       COUNT(`id`) AS 'active'
       FROM table1
      ) tmp1
      INNER JOIN
      (SELECT  name AS 'group',
       COUNT(`id`) AS 'participiants'   
       FROM table2
      ) tmp2 
ON tmp1.group=tmp2.group)
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS ord, 'TOTAL',
  SUM(tmp1.active) AS active_members,
  SUM(tmp2.participiants)
    FROM(
      (SELECT  name AS 'group',
       COUNT(`id`) AS 'active'
       FROM table1
      ) tmp1
      INNER JOIN
      (SELECT  name AS 'group',
       COUNT(`id`) AS 'participiants'   
       FROM table2
      ) tmp2 
ON tmp1.group=tmp2.group)
) AS tmp ORDER BY ord
```